How to plot coordinates on a map object in Jupyter notebook?
I'm new to working with the ArcGIS library. I've looked over the ArcGIS 2.4.0 documentation but still confused on how to plot coordinates onto a base map.
I tried finding examples of implementing something similar but was unsuccessful.
So far, I've run this.
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from arcgis.map import Map
from shapely.geometry import Point

#alcatraz island
coordinateX = -122.4230
coordinateY = 37.8270

coordinate = Point(coordinateX, coordinateY)

gis = GIS() #hiding GIS credentials

map = gis.map('San Francisco')
map.content.add(coordinate)
map

Although the map of San Francisco displays, there is no point plotted on Alcatraz Island.

The MapContent class's .add() method is for layers, the .draw() method is for shapes.
Also, use the ArcGIS API for Python's Point class instead of shapely's (will set a default spatial reference for your point of WGS84, or you can set your own).
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from arcgis.map import Map
from arcgis.geometry import Point

gis = GIS()

coordinate = Point([-122.4230, 37.8270])

map = gis.map('San Francisco')
map.content.draw(coordinate)
map


I tried finding examples of implementing something similar but was unsuccessful.

Here's a good example.

You've also assigned the coordinates differently from OP's code, in multiple ways. Will that matter or can it still work the way OP did it?

@TylerH Different point class/different constructor -- ArcGIS API for Python's point class (https://developers.arcgis.com/python/latest/api-reference/arcgis.geometry.html#arcgis.geometry.Point) expects an iterable or key word args, so OP's instantiation of shapely's point class won't work for ArcGIS API for Python's point class.
